# Different web domains SEO and PageRank

Tags: seo, domains, ranking

Which are differences between buying domains such as:

- `.me`
- `.be`
- `.li`
- `.cn.com`
- `.ar.com`
- `.eu.com`
- `.com`

In terms of SEO and page ranking?

What's the main differences between `mysite.com` and `mysite.be` or `mysite.ar.com`?

If I buy `site.com` and other person buy `site.me` are there any advantages of owning `.com` domain?

Answer (score 1):

The biggest difference between top level domains is that some of them only rank in specific countries.   There is an [approved list of top level domain from Google](https://support.google.com/webmasters/answer/1347922?hl=en) that you can get to rank worldwide.  Other top level domains will only rank in the country for that top level domain.

So from your list: `.me`, `.eu.com`, and `.com` are generic top level domains that will be able to rank around the world but the other options are not good unless you are specifically targeting the users in the country for that top level domain.

It can be advantageous to own domains for specific countries as well as a generic top level domain.  Google allows you to publish the same content on multiple geo-targeted sites.   Your content can rank better with a specific geo-targeted site than with a generic top level domain in that country.  Especially if you slightly change the site for regional spelling differences, prices, and shipping options.

If two people own the same word under different generic top level domains, they are competing for the brand name on a global level.   At that point, you can get into trademark disputes when the domain isn't just a common word or phrase.  As far as Google is concerned, the domain with the most reputation is the one that comes out ahead in the search engine results at that point.